# voice of multiple youtube videos overlap in IE - inside the gallery

Tags: highslide

If you click [here on the Media Gallery](http://www.automationdirect.com/adc/Shopping/Catalog/Sensors_-z-_Encoders/Pressure_Gauges_-a-_Thermometers/Dial_Pressure_Gauges_%281.5,_2.0,_2.5_Inch_Dials%29/1.5_Inch_Dial_%28Steel_Case,_Brass_Wetted_Parts%29/G15-BD100-8CB) > Scroll through the photos to the Video.

Once you click on the video it opens up, then if you try to click a picture instead, the sound on the video never closes out. If you click the video again, it starts over on top of what was already started. I have to shut down the browser to get the video sound to close out.

It happens with all the products with the mediagallery feature and videos if you are using Internet Explorer 9 & 10.

I cannot find any resources to on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known problem, with no known solution. It all started with Windows update KB2817183, back in April.

The only way to "fix" it is, first, to make sure you have `hs.objectLoadTime = 'after'`. That takes care of a single video that's being opened, then closed. But as part of a gallery, that's not enough. You also need to switch to `hs.transitions = ['fade']`. But that, in turn, triggers a different misbehavior, in which regular images randomly open without the expander, i.e., as if you have clicked on a link to a raw JPG image. The only fix for that is to eliminate the thumbstrip.

You might try `hs.transitions = ['expand']`, with no crossfade. I need to experiment with that a bit more. It's less than ideal, of course.

In short, you're trapped. My appeals to the Highslide JS developer have not produced any workaround.

Comment: I'm still pissed off that this thread was closed. There's no reason for that whatsoever. Try this beta version of the full Highslide JS script: http://www.highslide.com/highslide/highslide-full-issue-11-c.js